# How can I write .htaccess rules for multiple domain circumstances

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, mod-rewrite

I have two main types of domains directed to my web server. The main traffic (example.com) I want to direct to https, but the rest of the traffic (i.e. profile1.net, profile2.net, etc.) I want to leave as http. **For this reason, I can't use a catch-all SSL redirect type of rule.** Additionally, I have more rules that redirect profile names and hide extensions and such, so I can't use the L directive after the RewriteRule

I would also like to direct all the main traffic to include the subdomain www.

I can't seem to put the two pieces together, the system seems to ignore one of the conditions. Please review:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https://www.example.com/$1" [R=301]
```

*RESULTS: Test cases 3 & 4 work. Test cases 1 & 2 show as http://*

If I comment out the www. line in the conditional, the example.com works flawlessly:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https://www.example.com/$1" [R=301]
```

*RESULTS: Test cases 1, 3 & 4 work. Test case 2 shows as http://*

**Test cases:**

1. example.com -> https://www.example.com
2. www.example.com ->
   https://www.example.com
3. https://example.com ->
   https://www.example.com
4. https://www.example.com ->
   https://www.example.com

*These test cases do not apply for this example, but do in the overall *

5. [any of the above]/signup.php ->
   https://www.example.com/signup.php
6. profile.net -> profile.net
7. www.profile.net -> www.profile.net
8. https://profile.net -> THROWS
   SSL EXCEPTION IN BROWSER
9. https://www.profile.net -> THROWS SSL
   EXCEPTION IN BROWSER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a single 301 redirect rule for all 4 cases:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```